# Wordpress and Cloudfront Cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to use wordpress within an instance of AWS Cloudfront, but I'm getting an error in cloudfront link version that is not appearing on direct beanstalk link which doesn't allow me to do a post, the editor area and text is white.

I've set the wp-admin/* on cloudfront behaviors but is still not showing the same result.

Comment: Did you allow `POST` requests in CloudFront config?  Default is only `GET` and `HEAD` and `OPTIONS`.  Is there an actual error message?

Comment: I've fixed that error with a behavior to host server instead of cdn. I don't know why, tinymce plugin, a default wordpress plugin, has a php file on js folder, which by default is on cdn, but php doesn't work properly on cdn.